# How to use list of structs in c++

Tags: c++, list, struct

I would like to build a struct Packet that contains list of Headers. The relevant code I use:

```
//Packet.h
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Header {
    Header();
    bool Valid;
    long unsigned DestAddr:48;
};

struct Packet_t {
    Packet_t();
    list<Header> Headers;
};
```

Now I try to build the constructor for Packet_t that will initialize the Headers list to include only one header - FirstHeader:

```
//Packet.cpp
#include "Packet.h"

Header::Header() {
    Valid = false;
    DestAddr = 0;
};

Packet_t::Packet_t(){
    ValidPacket = false;
    Header FirstHeader(); //here I try to initialize the first Header using its constructor
    Headers.push_front(FirstHeader);
};
```

The error I get:

Packet.cpp: error: no matching function for call to 'std::list >::push_front(Header (&)())'

Really appreciate any help

Comment: `Header FirstHeader();` declared a function, not an object. Just use `Header FirstHeader;`

Comment: WhozCraig, but would it create an "initialized" Header object (as I defined the Header initialization in its constructor) ? Thank you

Comment: Also, stop putting `using namespace std` in header files. It's naughty..!

Comment: @Halona Yes, the default constructor (yours) is fired. Sadly this question is asked what seems like *daily*, but because everyone uses different names for different variables and classes, its difficult to link the *hundreds* of duplicates that already exist covering it. Its not an uncommon error, so don't feel you made some dreadful mistake.

Comment: Sean, Why (i'm very new to c++) ? It saves me from writing "std::" every tine, doesn't it?

Comment: @Halona Regarding `using namespace std;`, [that question I *can* link a reference to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452759/1322972) in particular is applicable to you.

Comment: Avoid using std::list unless you have a reason for it, otherwise use std::vector. And by "reason for it" I mean because the profiler told you.

Answer (score 7):

This is a function declaration:

```
Header FirstHeader();  // function FirstHeader, returns a Header
```

What you need is

```
Headers.push_front(Header());
```

or

```
Headers.emplace_front(); // default constructs FirstHeader object in place
```

or, if you need an instance to work on before pushing,

```
Header FirstHeader;
// ... do stuff to Header

Headers.push_front(FirstHeader);
```

Alternatively, use the constructor initialization list to initialize the list with one element:

```
Packet_t::Packet_t() : Headers(1) // or Headers{Header(args....) if need args
{

}
```

Comment: Ah, the most vexing parse rears its ugly head yet again.

Comment: @ÁtilaNeves this isn't an MVP. Its simply an declarative misstep. An MVP trips when attempting something similar, but actually providing a construction parameter which *also* happens to be intended as an immediate constructed temp: For example, consider: `Something obj(Thing())`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right, it is the "mildly vexing parse" MVP. This one doesn't make me do a double-take.